# strange error in javascript countdown

Tags: javascript, php, html

I'm building a webpage that shows multiple consecutive countdowns, depending from a text file.
Almost everything works now, only one thing still doesn't want to work.

***The problem is this***: when the timer hit's 00:00:00, it should switch to the next countdown, and start counting down, but what is does is showing some kind of glitch, it flashes between nan:nan:nan and 23:59:xx, like the countdown started again, counting down to the next day. I wrote some stuff to the console, and here I see that my function to set a new deadline in javascript is called, and the deadlinecounter does go up; but it goes up from 0 to 6 first, en later from 0 to 7. very strange I would say. Hope someone can help me!

this is my code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<!-- php functions -->
 <?php

$deadlineH      = null;
$deadlineM      = null;
$deadlineS      = null;
$deadlineTitle  = null;

$filename = "data.txt";
$fp = fopen($filename, "r");
$content = fread($fp, filesize($filename));

$fullArray = setFullArray($content);
$length = count($fullArray);
for ($i = 0; $i < $length - 1; $i++) {
  $value = $fullArray[$i];
  echo "var " . ($i + 1)  . ": " . $fullArray[$i] ." <br>";
  if((($i+1) % 4) == 0){
    echo "   ";
  }
}

 $hoursArray = [];
 $minutesArray = [];
 $secondsArray = [];
 $titlesArray = [];
 setArrays($fullArray);

 function setArrays($fullArray){
   $length = count($fullArray);
   for ($i=0; $i < $length - 1; $i = $i+4) {
     array_push($GLOBALS['hoursArray'], $fullArray[$i]);
   }
   for ($j=1; $j < $length - 1; $j = $j+4) {
     array_push($GLOBALS['minutesArray'], $fullArray[$j]);
   }
   for ($k=2; $k < $length - 1; $k = $k+4) {
     array_push($GLOBALS['secondsArray'], $fullArray[$k]);
   }
   for ($l=3; $l < $length - 1; $l = $l+4) {
     array_push($GLOBALS['titlesArray'], $fullArray[$l]);
   }
 }



$numberoflines = getNumberOflines($fullArray);
echo "number of lines: " . $numberoflines . "<br>";
showDeadlines($fullArray);

function setFullArray($content){
  $fullArray =  preg_split("/(:|\n)/" ,$content);         // splits the whole data txt file into small chunks, everything apart
  return $fullArray;
}

function getNumberOflines($fullArray){
  $numberoflines = (sizeof($fullArray) - 1) / 4;
  return $numberoflines;
}

function showDeadlines($fullArray){ // won't be used in final thing
  $length = count($fullArray);
  for ($i=0; $i < $length-1; $i =  $i + 4) {
    $deadlineNumber = ($i + 4)/4;
    $deadlineH = $fullArray[$i];
    $deadlineM = $fullArray[$i+1];
    $deadlineS = $fullArray[$i+2];
    $deadlineTitle = $fullArray[$i+3];
    echo "deadline " . $deadlineNumber . ": " . $deadlineH . ":" . $deadlineM . ":" . $deadlineS . " titel : " . $deadlineTitle . "<br>";
  }
}

function setDeadline($fullArray){
  $length = count($fullArray);
  for ($i=0; $i < $length-1; $i =  $i + 4) {
    $deadlineNumber = ($i + 4)/4;
    $GLOBALS['deadlineH'] = $fullArray[$i];
    $GLOBALS['deadlineM'] = $fullArray[$i+1];
    $GLOBALS['deadlineS'] = $fullArray[$i+2];
    $GLOBALS['deadlineTitle'] = $fullArray[$i+3];
  }
}

?>
<!-- end php functions -->

<html>
<head>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css">
</head>

<body onload="startTime()">

<div id="visible">
<div id="clock"><span> </span> </div><br>
<div id="countdown">  </div>
<div id="countdown">  </div>
<div id="title"> </div>
</div>
  <p>
  <?php
    echo json_encode($hoursArray);
    echo json_encode($minutesArray);
    echo json_encode($secondsArray);
    echo json_encode($titlesArray);
  ?>
  </p>
</div>

<!-- javascript scripts -->
<script>

var hoursArray = [];
var minutesArray = [];
var secondsArray = [];
var titlesArray = [];
var deadlineCounter;

function startTime() {
    var now = new Date();
    // year, month, day, hours, minutes, seconds, milliseconds
    var deadline = new Date(2016, 11, 20, 00 ,00 ,00 ,00);
    deadlineCounter = 0;
    var clockH = now.getHours();
    var clockM = now.getMinutes();
    var clockS = now.getSeconds();

    setArrays();
    setInitialDeadline(deadline);
    startClock('clock');
    startCountdown('countdown', deadline);
    var t = setTimeout(startTime, 500);
}

function setArrays(){
  hoursArray= <?php echo json_encode($hoursArray); ?>;
  console.log( hoursArray );

  minutesArray= <?php echo json_encode($minutesArray); ?>;
  console.log( minutesArray );

  secondsArray= <?php echo json_encode($secondsArray); ?>;
  console.log( secondsArray );

  titlesArray= <?php echo json_encode($titlesArray); ?>;
  console.log( titlesArray );
}

function setInitialDeadline(deadline) {
  deadline.setHours(hoursArray[0]);
  deadline.setMinutes(minutesArray[0]);
  deadline.setSeconds(secondsArray[0]);
  document.getElementById("title").innerHTML = titlesArray[0];
}

function setNewDeadline(deadline){
  console.log('new deadline set');
  deadline.setHours(hoursArray[deadlineCounter]);
  deadline.setMinutes(minutesArray[deadlineCounter]);
  deadline.setSeconds(secondsArray[deadlineCounter]);
  document.getElementById("title").innerHTML = titlesArray[deadlineCounter];
}

function getCountdown(deadline){
    var countdownTotal =  Date.parse(deadline) - Date.parse(new Date());
    var countdownS =      Math.floor( (countdownTotal/1000) % 60 );
    var countdownM =      Math.floor( (countdownTotal/1000/60) % 60 );
    var countdownH =      Math.floor( (countdownTotal/(1000*60*60)) % 24 );
    return{
      'countdownTotal':   countdownTotal,
      'countdownH':       countdownH,
      'countdownM':       countdownM,
      'countdownS':       countdownS
    }
}

function startClock(id){
  var clock = document.getElementById(id);
  var timeInterval = setInterval(function(){
    var now = new Date();
    var nowH = now.getHours();
    var nowM = now.getMinutes();
    var nowS = now.getSeconds();
    nowH = checkTime(nowH);
    nowM = checkTime(nowM);
    nowS = checkTime(nowS);

    clock.innerHTML = nowH + ':' + nowM + ':' + nowS;
  }, 1000);
}

function startCountdown(id, deadline){
  var countdown = document.getElementById(id);
  var timeInterval = setInterval(function(){
    var t = getCountdown(deadline);


    //console.log(t);
    //console.log(deadlineCounter);
    countdown.innerHTML = checkTime(t.countdownH) + ':' + checkTime(t.countdownM) + ':' + checkTime(t.countdownS);
    if(t.countdownH == 0 && t.countdownM == 0 && t.countdownS == 0){
      deadlineCounter++;
      setNewDeadline(deadline);
      t = getCountdown(deadline);
    }
  }, 1000);
}

function checkTime(i) {
    if (i < 10) {i = "0" + i};  // add zero in front of numbers < 10
    return i;
}
</script>
<!-- //end javascript -->

</body>
</html>
```

Thanks!

Comment: You defined `<div id="countdown">  </div>`  twice with the same `id`. It's a mistake.

Comment: this was indeed a mistake, but doesn't provide an answer for my problem...

Comment: Is it correct to call function `startTime()` inside itself like this: `var t = setTimeout(startTime, 500);`. Maybe it's better to remove this line from func body and write: `<body onload="setTimeout(startTime(), 500)">`.

Comment: Nice, that actually did it, thanks! Do you happen to have an idea on why I cant do a countdown to the next day, so over 24 hours with this code?

Comment: You need to add and use at least a parameter `Day` by method `.getDay()`. If deadline comes over a month, then you'll need to deal with `.getMonth()` too.

Comment: two items with the same id is not a mistake but a not valid markup and will cause your code to behave not properly. fix the id first, adapt your code accordingly (if you need to reference more than one item at the same time use classes)

Comment: I don't understand why in my getCountdown function, for exemple, the hours, can't get bigger than 24 even if the deadline is set in a week, and now is still today...@Banzay

Comment: Because a func `Date.parse` converts trivial date in to milliseconds.  Then this value is used for calculating seconds, minutes and hours. Next step is - countdown (timer) hours have divided by 24, thus countdown hours can not exceed 24. If you want a countdown could exceed nearest 24 hours, try to modify a corresponding line: `var countdownH =      Math.floor( (countdownTotal/(1000*60*60)) % 24 );` - remove a chunk `% 24`. Then It has to look: `var countdownH =      Math.floor(countdownTotal/(1000*60*60));` It's my assumption. Anyway a programmer is you in this place.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Correct calling the function `startTime()` inside itself like this: `var t = setTimeout(startTime, 500);`. Maybe it's better to remove this line from func body and write:

```
<body onload="setTimeout(startTime(), 500)">
```